# Kth smallest Element in two sorted array - Error

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement the program to find  kth Smallest element in two sorted array. So far I came up with :

```
public static int kSmallest(int[] a, int[] b, int aStart, int aEnd,
      int bStart, int bEnd, int k) {
    int lena = aEnd - aStart + 1;
    int lenb = bEnd - bStart + 1;

    if (lena == 0) {
      return b[k - 1];
    }

    if (lenb == 0) {
      return a[k - 1];
    }

    if (k == 1) {
      return Math.min(a[aStart], b[bStart]);
    }

    if(lena + lenb == k){
        return Math.max(a[aEnd], b[bEnd]);
    }

    int i = lena / 2;
    int j = lenb / 2;

    int ma = a[i];
    int mb = b[j];

    if (i + j > k) {
      if (ma < mb) {
        return kSmallest(a, b, i + 1, aEnd, bStart, j - 1, k - i);
      } else {
        return kSmallest(a, b, aStart, i - 1, j + 1, bEnd, k - j);
      }
    } else {
      if (ma < mb) {
        return kSmallest(a, b, i + 1, aEnd, bStart, j - 1, k);
      } else {
        return kSmallest(a, b, aStart, i - 1, j + 1, bEnd, k);
      }
    }

  }
```

But it gives error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at arrays.MedianArray.kSmallest(MedianArray.java:90)
    at arrays.MedianArray.kSmallest(MedianArray.java:117)
    at arrays.MedianArray.kSmallest(MedianArray.java:115)
    at arrays.MedianArray.kSmallest(MedianArray.java:115)
    at arrays.MedianArray.main(MedianArray.java:18)
```

Can some one tell me what is wrong in my program ? I am getting index out of bound exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand what you want to do, but as I can see you always reduce your k, lena, lenb. And k has been redused at a faster pace than lena and lenb, therefore when lena or lenb is equals 0, k is less 0. As a result these rows:

```
if (lena == 0) {
  return b[k - 1];
}

if (lenb == 0) {
  return a[k - 1];
}
```

lead to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
public static int kSmallest(int[] a, int[] b, int aStart, int aEnd,
          int bStart, int bEnd, int k)
{
    int[] aa = new int[aEnd-aStart];
    java.lang.System.arraycopy(a, aStart, aa, 0, aa.length);

    int[] bb = new int[bEnd-bStart];
    java.lang.System.arraycopy(b, bStart, bb, 0, bb.length);

    if(k>aa.length || k>bb.length)
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    return aa[k]<bb[k] ? aa[k] : bb[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Since you start at `aStart` and `bStart`, shouldn't these cases be:

```
if (lena == 0) {
  return b[bStart + k - 1];
}

if (lenb == 0) {
  return a[aStart + k - 1];
}
```

You should also probably check if BOTH arrays are empty `(lena == 0 && lenb == 0)` or else you're going to be trying to access an index of an empty array.

I'm sure there's something wrong with this chunk:

```
if (i + j > k) {
  if (ma < mb) {
    return kSmallest(a, b, i + 1, aEnd, bStart, j - 1, k - i);
  } else {
    return kSmallest(a, b, aStart, i - 1, j + 1, bEnd, k - j);
  }
} else {
  if (ma < mb) {
    return kSmallest(a, b, i + 1, aEnd, bStart, j - 1, k);
  } else {
    return kSmallest(a, b, aStart, i - 1, j + 1, bEnd, k);
  }
}
```

Try `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `b = [7,8,9,10,11,12]` with `k = 2`. You would expect to get `2` back. `i` and `j` are both `3` in the first stack, and `ma` and `mb` would be `4` and `10` respectively. Your code would enter the `if (i + j > k)` block, then the `if (ma < mb)` block. Then it would search for the `k-i`th smallest term... But `k-i` is -1 in this case! Something's wrong.

I would suggest you to maybe write out the pseudocode for your cases first, and make sure you understand what you're doing in each scenario. Then you can continue and code it.